# Unitary matrix $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Suppose $z_1,z_2$ are two complex variables. Consider the subset $X = \{ z_1 + z_2 = 0\} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$. I would like to construct a unitary map that takes $X$ to the set $Y = \{ z_1 =0 \}$. Any suggestions for how I would go about constructing such a matrix? Note that this is not a homework problem, it relates to a bigger problem that I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

A real orthogonal matrix would suffice. You want an operator that sends a subspace spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ to a subspace spanned by $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$, and this can be achieved by a simple rotation
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}.$$
The way to construct such a matrix is as follows: take the basis vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$, send them to $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$, respectively. This gives you the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix},$$
but you need the inverse operator, so just invert this matrix (and normalize to make columns have length $1$).

Answer (score 0):

You want $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in U(2)$ such that the first component of $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} z \\ -z \end{pmatrix}$ (which is $az - bz$) be $0$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$. This quickly implies that $a=b$. Using this, unitarity means that

$$\begin{pmatrix} a & a \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \bar a & \bar c \\ \bar a & \bar d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 |a|^2 & a (\bar c + \bar d) \\ \bar a (c + d) & |c|^2 + |d|^2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} ,$$

which gives $|a| = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}$, $c+d = 0$ and $|c|^2 + |d|^2 = 1$. It immediately follows that $c = -d$, so $|c| = |d| = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}$.

To summarize, every matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & a \\ c & -c \end{pmatrix}$ with $|a| = |c| = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ is good, so the solution to your problem is not unique. In particular, you may take $a = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ and $c = - \dfrac 1 {\sqrt 2}$ to obtain your matrix real and in $SU(2)$, but this is not the only posibility.